# EditText loses background on selection

Tags: xml, android-edittext, android-drawable

I have an `EditText` box that has a custom `drawable` background, but whenever you select the `EditText` to input something the background disappears and makes the text impossible to read (it is the same color as the app background)

Here is what I am talking about:

[image]

[image]

The background just disappears and I am not sure why this is happening. This is my `.xml`

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/enterCode"
    android:layout_width="237sp"
    android:layout_height="55sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:autofillHints="true"
    android:background="@drawable/rect_yellow_border"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Game PIN"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textColorHint="#40292929"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/products_toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.309" />
```

I have also tried to set the background in `Java` but the issue is not fixed when I tried doing that either. Any help?

Here is my `drawable` file. It is a bit unnecessary and weird because I just edited the code of one of my rounded shapes and made it into a square

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
            <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#ffc847" />
            <gradient android:angle="-180" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#ffc847" />
            <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#ffc847" />
            <solid android:color="#ffc847"/>
            <gradient android:angle="-45" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>


</selector>
```

In my `Activity` all I have done to define this `EditText` is this:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_private_room_lobby);
    final Button createPrivateGame = findViewById(R.id.createPrivateGame);
    final Button joinPrivateRoom = findViewById(R.id.joinPrivateGame);
    final EditText pinEntry = findViewById(R.id.enterCode);

    joinPrivateRoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String pin = pinEntry.getText().toString().trim();
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(pin) || pin.length() > 6 || pin.length() < 6)
            {
                Toast.makeText(PrivateRoomLobby.this, "Please enter a 6 digit PIN to enter the room", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                joinGame(pin);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: share rect_yellow_border drawable code and your Activity code

Comment: @AD10 updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selector is used to defining `view` component’s background color or background image by its various state. for more detail check [this](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-shape-selector-examples/)

you need to use the only `shape`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >



    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#ffc847" />

    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
  <!--  <gradient android:angle="-45" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:endColor="#ffffff" />-->

</shape>
```